# Unable to solve LNK2019 and LNK2021 error when linking one lib (C++ based) with another (CUDA based)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, cuda, linker-errors

I am trying to port a library from Linux to Windows, the library is made up of two libs, one is a completely CUDA based library that is built separately and the other is C++ based and is linked to the CUDA based library.

The library had used dynamic arrays which weren't allowed by MSVC so I converted them to vectors and tested them successfully on Linux, but on windows I ran into bunch of windows linker issues like `LNK2019` and `LNK2001`, mainly when functions in the C++ library refer to the ones in CUDA based library, like this for example:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
> activationMishForward(float *,float *,int,struct CUstream_st *)"
> (?activationMishForward@@YAXPEAM0HPEAUCUstream_st@@@Z) referenced in
> function "public: virtual int __cdecl
> dnn::ActivationMishRT::enqueue(int,void const * const *,void * *,void
> *,struct CUstream_st *)" (?enqueue@ActivationMishRT@dnn@tk@@UEAAHHPEBQEBXPEAPEAXPEAXPEAUCUstream_st@@@Z)

This error doesn't seem to change even if I don't link to the CUDA based library, it seems like for some reason it is unable to resolve symbols even when I link to the lib.

Can someone explain what is happening here and how I should fix the linking errors?

Comment: You could run `DUMPBIN /SYMBOLS` on the CUDA library, see what names it actually exports. If I had to guess, I'd suspect the function is exported under a plain undecorated name, and you need `extern "C"` to link to it from C++.

Comment: I did try using extern "C" ,but it still didn't work.Maybe i am using it in a wrong way,can you maybe give an example on how to use it properly ?

Answer (score 1):

That means that this function you are trying to use  `activationMishForward(float *,float *,int,struct CUstream_st *)` is not found in the library, even if one type of its parameters doesn't match the one inside the library, the result will be the same.
Make sure you are using the functions exactly as defined inside the library.